# calculating port address from base address in 8255

Tags: microprocessor

if the 8255A has a base address of FFF9H. then how will I calculate the address of PORT A,B,C and control register?

I have made a calculation as the following. adding 1 each time with the base address to generate the rest others:

```
PORT A:FFFAH
PORT B:FFFBH
PORT C:FFFCH
Control register: FFFDH
```

is the process ok or have I made anything wrong in the calculation?

Comment: How is the chip select (CS) selected, i.e. which address pins go into the logic which controls it? What address signals are the address lines, A0 and A1, connected to? It looks weird to have the device selected by FFF9H. A simple approach would be to have chip select controlled with an address with the two lowest bits set to 0 (and not used by the chip select logic), and the two lowest address bits connected directly to A1 and A0.

Answer (score 1):

Typically your base address will be a multiple of the number of addresses uses by your device (in your case 4).
Although it is possible to finangle a way to have the base at any address, this would be uncommon and require extra address decoding logic instead of just connecting the lower 2 bits of your address bus directly to the 8255.

So what this means is that your base address should have its lower 2 bits as 0's leading to, in your case FFF8h.
With a Base address of FFF8h:
 - PortA will be at FFF8h
 - PortB will be at FFF9h
 - PortC will be at FFFAh
 - Control will be at FFFBh

If you do decide to implement the extra logic to get a base address of FFF9h, then this is going to be PortA's address, with B, C & Control following form there (assuming you don't do anything else 'interesting' with the address lines).

Comment: in the book the ans is as follows: FFF9, FFFB, FFFD, FFFF, for PORT A,B,C and control register accordingly @brhans

Comment: While it is certainly a possibility, there isn't sufficient detail in your question to lead to that result alone. As gbulmer commented on your question, how the chip-select and address lines are connected will make a difference.

Comment: @user6216509 This is different from your original question.  So if the ports are FFF9, FFFB, FFFD, FFFF, write the last digit down as binary and you will see which bits are being used to access the 4 ports.

Answer (score 1):

> in the book the ans is as follows: FFF9, FFFB, FFFD, FFFF, for PORT
>   A,B,C and control

This is what you might expect from a system with a 16 bit data bus. The 8255 only has 8 data lines, which would be connected to either the lower or upper 8 CPU data lines. If the CPU is 'little-ended' then the upper data byte (bits 15-8) is accessed at odd addresses.

Since address line A0 selects the lower or upper byte on the data bus, it must always be high (for the upper byte) or low (for the lower byte) and cannot be used for addressing registers in the 8255. If you use A1 and A2 for register addressing and the 8255 data bus connected to D15-8 then you get the port addresses in your book.